# How to join domain table with second table using two foreign keys for one primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, inner-join

I have two tables as follows:

TABLE1 (domain table):

| ITEM_ID (PK) | ITEM_NAME | ITEM_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Orange | 123 |
| 2 | Apple | 321 |
| 3 | Banana | 131 |
| 4 | Melon | 312 |

TABLE2:

| CART_ID (PK) | CART_NAME | ITEM1_FK (FK1) | ITEM2_FK (FK2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Cart11 | 1 | 3 |
| 16 | Cart16 | 2 | 2 |
| 85 | Cart85 | 3 | 4 |
| 96 | Cart96 | 4 | 1 |

Both FKs from TABLE2 points to TABLE1's PK. My question is how can I create a `SELECT` statement that joins the tables above into something like that:

| CART_ID (PK) | CART_NAME | ITEM1_NAME | ITEM1_PRICE | ITEM2_NAME | ITEM2_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Cart11 | Orange | 123 | Banana | 131 |

I tried using `INNER JOIN` operations with both the FKs, but I always get ambiguous column name error or manage to create a table in which both "*ITEM_NAME*" and "*ITEM_PRICE*" fields have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alias the tables and join them twice.  Try something like:

```
SELECT      t.cart_id,
            t.cart_name,
            a.item_name item1_name,
            a.item_price item1_price,
            b.item_name item2_name,
            b.item_price item2_price
FROM        table2 t
INNER JOIN  table1 a
ON          t.item1_fk = a.item_id
INNER JOIN  table1 b
ON          t.item2_fk = b.item_id
;
```

That said, this isn't a great table design, considering it has the number of items in a cart hard-coded, but that's a different story.